# What is the best way to request HTTP resources in an application that could be decompiled?

Tags: java

I'm working on an java application that needs to store some form of info into a database, which since .jar files can be decompiled, using DBC is out of the question. How would one be able to store info in a database via http requests in a way that would allow the application to work but not allow a malicious user to store fake data? Sorry if this a stupid or vague question, I'm having trouble figuring out how to phrase it.

Comment: So... *what* is it that you're trying to do, again?

Comment: I have an application (.jar) that people would be running on their computers. I need to store info into a database from it, and assuming that the .jar can be decompiled, I can't use DBC as that would expose credentials. I assume it's possible to use HTTP(S) for this, but how can I do it in such a way that the application can send data but a malicious user can't send fake data?

Comment: Are you looking for how to make HTTP requests with Java? Your application shouldn't be the security layer, your backend should handle the security implementation.

Comment: So you're trying to secure requests, and also ensure that the requests are valid?

Comment: If a web user can get access you .jars to decompile them you have bigger problems than worrying about storing fake data.

Comment: @MikeElofson Yes, I am. I'm not sure how the security would be implemented to make this work, and googling didn't show me anything.

Comment: @TheHeadRush It's a downloadable jar application.

Comment: Security in and of itself is very broad; just "how to implement a secure service like Spring-OAuth" is huge...

Comment: Gotcha. Is the database embedded in the jar or does the application communicate with it across a network?

Comment: @TheHeadRush The database is on a remote server, so it is not in the jar. My concern here is even using a system with 1-token-per-input to the database, the tokens still have to come from somewhere and they can just generate more of them.

Comment: @VoidWhisperer Have the user authenticate themselves with a user-password combo, and store a seession in an `HttpClient` that you intend to make requests with. Then, on the backend, check whether or not the session included a user. If it did, make sure they have permission to do whatever it is you want to do, otherwise return a 401.

Answer (score 0):

You should have your user enter some authenitcating credentials into your applicaiton at run time rather than store those credentials in the jar.